# How to set up redirection from one page to another within the same site on a Windows computer

Tags: windows, url, redirect, browser, hosts

How to set up redirection from one page to another within the same site on a Windows computer (The site is not mine). For example, from https://seller.wildberries.ru/ to https://seller.wildberries.ru/marketplace-orders-new/new-tasks/to-warehouse

This is necessary to ensure the safety of data in the personal account of the marketplace seller. So that the employee does not have access to pages with financial information. The personal account of the wildberries.ru marketplace does not have access restrictions for different employees, so you have to come up with your own solution

Blocking through the hosts file, firewall, router occurs by IP address. This does not suit me, as it will block all traffic from this IP

Comment: You *are* aware that this is a `https` URL, right? That is to say, a secure site? Which specifically means that it is protected against Man-In-The-Middle attacks like you are proposing. You're about two decades too late for this sort of thing. Even the `hosts` tag stopped making sense a few years ago. Modern browers don't trust that anymore and use DNS over HTTPS.